# Combining Pie chart with stacked area chart using highcharts

Tags: .net, highcharts

I have a requirement of combining Pie chart with stacked area chart using highcharts one below the other and it should have legends, On click of the legend, both the charts i.e. Pie and Stacked area graph should reflect with actual values.

Comment: Okay, what have you tried so far?

Comment: My script goes like this :

Comment: yes I have tried but dint get as expected, the sample i have saved in jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/aqphezkv/5/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aqphezkv/6/ You need to do the same thing for the stacked series as for the pie points.